# Pymodbus – Listen for input change on PLC device

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot, modbus, pymodbus

I am programming a PLC device (Moxa ioLogik E1214) and have connected the DI ports to buttons, and the coils are connected to LED lights. The idea is that when you press a button, the LED should light up.

I have gotten the program to work if you hold down the button until the read input function executes. The problem is that I'd like to set a time frame (X seconds) and if the button is pressed (and not held down) within this timeframe the light should toggle.

The code is below:

```
import time
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from pprint import pprint
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

moxaA = ModbusClient('XX.XX.XX.XX', port=502)

print "Press a button now"

time.sleep(2)
result = moxaA.read_input_registers(0x30, 1)
if result:
    pressedBtn = result.registers[0]
    if pressedBtn == 1:
        moxaA.write_coil(0, 1)
    else: 
        moxaA.write_coil(0, 0)
```

As you can see I've set a timeout for the reading of the input registers. But how can I "listen" for an input change within these seconds, and not have to hold the button down until the read input registers function executes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some arguments (`unit`, `connect`, `isError()`).

---

I improved your snippet code:

```
moxaA = ModbusClient('XX.XX.XX.XX', port=502)

if moxaA.connect()
    print "Press a button now"
    time.sleep(2)
    result = moxaA.read_input_registers(0x30, 1, unit=1)

    if not result.isError():
        pressedBtn = result.registers[0]

        if pressedBtn == 1:
            moxaA.write_coil(0, 1, unit=1)
        else: 
            moxaA.write_coil(0, 0, unit=1)
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- With the above `sleep(2)` you should press the button 2 seconds or after 2 seconds.
- `isError()` defined in the *pymodbus 1.4.0* and above.
- You should specify the `unit`, in many cases `unit` is equal `1`.

Comment: Thank you for the improvements, much appreciated. However, is it possible to instead of having a time.sleep() to add some kind of javascript's eventListener to listen for a button press, and then return the input register?

Comment: @user2868900 I don't know about how with js, but you can use a `while` instead of `time.sleep()`

Comment: I did, thank you for the help. I will post a reply with the solution